# XeTeX errors when compiling in Windows?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, windows

I am in the process of transitioning from using Texpad and BibDesk on Mac OS to trying to find something that works for me on Windows.

When I try to compile on e.g. TexMaker or TexStudio using the latest TexLive distribution (and JabRef as my bibliography manager for .bib file if that's relevant), I get the following errors:

[image]

It seems there's a problem with XeTeX. The editor does compile a PDF though. The PDF is fine except that the citations have been replaced by question marks. I'm not sure if this is related to the XeTeX issue or is a separate problem. Total amateur with LaTeX would really, really value any input.

**Edit** in repsonse to a request for a minimal working example, I tried just creating a simple document and got an error message:

[image]

Is this because my distribution is in the wrong path? Apologies for being so terrible at this and thanks in advance for any suggestions

**Edit 2** This is the original error message:

[image]

As you can see, AFAIK, I am running it with Lualatex. Problem replicates with Xelatex. TexMaker doesn't appear to have Xetex (unlike Texpad).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you somehow isolate the problem and then post a compilable minimal working example (which may well throw errors of course)? This way, others will be able to help you. With just this screenshot we can only guess the cause of your problem.

Comment: The error messages of texmaker don't show everything. Better look in the log-file.

Comment: the errors show that you have used pdflatex instead of xelatex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oops :-) ^^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh. I didn't look at the last one ;-)

Comment: texmaker texpad etc are just editors they do not "have" tex or luatex or anything else) It would be rather unlikely that you have obtained a tex distribution without xetex. you can test by running `xelatex mytestfile.tex` in a command window

Comment: as in, running that code in TexMaker?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would it be possible to just chat with you directly?

Comment: you would be better to wait for someone who has texmaker to answer and show  how the commands should be configred, I do not have it. but as I say you shoudl be able to run tex without using the editor at all, open a command window (or powershell if you prefer) and cd to the folder with your file and type `xelatex yourfileame`

Comment: thanks. when i type that code into command prompt it says "xelatex is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Answer (score 1):

Your document requires xelatex, but (as shown in the last error that you show) you are using pdflatex. You should be able to switch to xelatex in the editor menus.

Comment: thank you so much, and thanks to others too. I tried constructing a minimal example per @Jasper Habicht. But when I try to compile (LaTeX, PDFLaTeX, or Xelatex) I get an error saying "log file not found". Is this because my distribution is not in the correct path? (I hope you guys have patience to help out a noob)

Comment: @nathanglass the log file not found usually means tex did not run at all (often because it has not been installed, if you just install the editor) but the original error image that you showed clearly showed tex error messages from pdftex, so there seems to be a contradiction, what happens if you run the original document, do you get the tex errors or "no log" ?

Comment: Thank you once again. Please see the 2nd edit to the original question. When I run the original document, it compiles a PDF but I get the tex error messages.

Comment: Hi @David Carlise, would you be amenable to chatting about this? I am happy to use whatever editor you recommend (if you're not TexMaker). I don't have enough reputation to use the chat room unfortunately...